# Making my own website analytics

Tags: php, sql, analytics

I decided that Google Analytics isn't the best way to go around getting accurate numbers, as users who don't have JavaScript enabled in their browser wont be counted. So therefore I would like to go around making my own Anylytics.

I have a table which will record the user's ip address, the page URL and the date/time.

I then have a script that is at the bottom of every page on the site, which will then run an SQL query to submit the data into a database.

Here's the script.

```
$page_viewed = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
     $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
     $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
     $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
$ip = mysql_real_escape_string($ip);
mysql_query("And then do the sql query.... ");
```

As most of you here are experience developers, I want to know if you had any improvements on my scripts or anything that needs amending.

Comment: If you're just asking for general feedback, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is probably more appropriate.

Comment: If accuracy is your main requirement, you are better off sticking with Google Analytics, or a paid service like GoSquared or Mint. Implementing a reliable analytics solution that doesn't kill your server is much harder than you think. For a start, your solution above is going to require an SQL insert query for every single page load. If you have more than, say, 100 requests per second that can really slow down your server. If you're not getting that kind of load, then is there any point in worrying about the few users that don't have JavaScript enabled?

Comment: People who don't forward refers won't be counted properly either. It is essentially IMPOSSIBLE to have 100% reliable web analytics.

Comment: I recommend you to have a look at this [link](http://hangupin.com/web-analytics-recorder-php-tutorial/)

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a bad idea... Generally what happens for analytics is when the user doesn't support javascript, their browser parses what is contained in the  html tags. Generally in these you can contain a single pixel image or something similar (the purpose of the image is to call code like you have given above). Use this request to get the information about clients who don't have javascript capabilities, rather than sticking everyone into the same boat.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Apache, this is all recorded anyway in your log files. You can use something like http://awstats.sourceforge.net/ to analyse them.

Logging with MySQL and PHP is going to kill your server if you have the kind of no-JS-enabled traffic that's worth analysing.

Answer (score 0):

As @Blowski mentioned above, there are better options.  I've used [Mint](http://haveamint.com/) in the past and it's an incredible service. It's written in PHP an is both beautiful to study and easy to understand.

I encourage you to spend some time looking at its [feature highlights](http://haveamint.com/about/feature_highlights) as well as the [screencasts and screenshots](http://haveamint.com/about/screencasts_and_screenshots) before you spend more time looking reinvent the wheel - your time is valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Because browser cache and javascript, you will find log files analysis is not 100% accurate too. Combining log analysis and page tagging is best choice for most web site. I'd used [Nihuo](http://www.loganalyzer.net) and google analytics both in past years, they work great for me.